# Problem in reading properties of an tag in an jquery variable which holds entire code of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I'm working on fetching id of element in an html file that includes multiple tables and id will be unique 3 digit words.Help me how will I get those ID's.     Below is my code

```
<html lang="en">
            $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
       url: 'gethtmlcode.php',                       
       success: function (response) {
         resp = response;                   //resp contains source code of html file
            });
            });     
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Below is my html code. It contains many tables and div. I want to get id's of all tables and div's id that is dynamically generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
         <table id="table1">

      <div id="157">
         <br>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Test ID</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>157</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Test Plan Name</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>Validation-Current Day</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        </div>
                <div id="200">
         <br>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Test ID</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>157</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Test Plan Name</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>Eligibility Current Day</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        </div>


         </table>
      </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with the code as it is right now?  What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: Code is fetching entire code of an html file and that will be stored in "resp" variable. I want to get id's of all table tag. All id's will be unique and dynamically generated. That is where I'm stuck. Please help me how will I get those id's.

Comment: Gotcha!  Can you please put that into your question, so people don't have to dig through the comments to figure out what the problem is?  I'm sure you'll get a good answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an table id from html variable you can use the next code

```js
var response ="<html><body><table id='table1'><tbody></tbody></table></body><table id='table2'><tbody></tbody></table></body></html>";
console.log($('<div />', {html: response}).find('table').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for multiple tables you'll need to use `.each()` to loop through tables to get each table id

```js
var response ="<html><body><table id='table1'><tbody></tbody></table></body><table id='table2'><tbody></tbody></table></body></html>";
$('<div />', {html: response}).find('table').each(function(){
  console.log(this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot @Mohamed-Yousef . Worked like a charm.

Comment: You're totally welcome @newbie22 .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: if "Test ID" is found, how to get the "157" i.e., the very 2nd td value now.Can you please help.

Comment: simple @newbie22 .. in.`each()`  use `console.log($(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td:eq(0)').text().trim())` .. `:eq(0)` mean first one .. to et a third one use `'td:eq(2)'`